# Template to compute size of Eigen matrix or tuple type object

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to write some generic code which can compute the size of some data. This size is basically the number of elements in an array/tuple like structure or in an Eigen matrix.

I have tried the following

```
template <typename T>
constexpr int getDataSize(T /*t*/)
{
    return std::tuple_size_v<T>;
}

template <typename Derived>
constexpr int getDataSize(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> /*t*/)
{
    using T = Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>;
    return T ::RowsAtCompileTime * T::ColsAtCompileTime;
}
```

but the compiler is always trying to instantiate the first template, also when I pass an Eigen matrix. Since `tuple_size_v` doesn't exist for Eigen object, it doesn't compile.

Example in https://godbolt.org/z/d6T638K1e

How could I compute this size in a generic way?

Answer (score 0):

The minimal fix is:

```
template <typename ...P>
constexpr int getDataSize(std::tuple<P...>)
{
    return sizeof...(P);
}
```

Or, to also support `std::pair`s and `std::array`s:

```
template <typename T>
requires requires{std::tuple_size<T>::value;} // Because `tuple_size_v` is not SFINAE-friendly.
constexpr int getDataSize(T)
{
    return std::tuple_size_v<T>;
}
```

Also the parameters (both tuple and Eigen matrix) should be passed by const references, to avoid copies.

Or, better, since you ignore the values anyway, you should be using a class/variable template instead of a function.

Comment: Passing the parameter is indeed unneded, I was just passing it to let template deduction work. Unrelated though. That `requires requires` is the first time I see it. Its C++17?

Comment: @jjcasmar C++20. *"was just passing it to let template deduction work"* That's why I suggest a class instead. Something like: `num_elems<decltype(x)>::value`, or `num_elems_v<decltype(x)>`. A bit more verbose, but can be called without an instance of the type, which is sometimes useful.

Comment: Any option to do it with C++17?